# LINQ to SQL insert into database from html form

Tags: c#, sql, forms, linq

I am having an issue with inserting into a database using an Table object I created. It is not taking any of the values into the the object when using `Request.Form["inputID"] All of my objects attributes are NULL but as I stepped through the program I found the following Request.Form Information while debugging.

> - Request.Form    {ctl00%24MainContent%24custFullName=Test+Tester&ctl00%24MainContent%24custPhoneNum=555-555-555&ctl00%24MainContent%24roadService=empty+gas+tank&ctl00%24MainContent%24carYearDB=2003&ctl00%24MainContent%24carMakeDB=BMW&ctl00%24MainContent%24carModelDB=3+Series&submitQuote=Get+Quote}   System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
>     {System.Web.HttpValueCollection}

All values are accounted for but I am not understanding why they aren't being taken into the database.

My form tag is as follows:

```
<form action="Default.aspx" method="post" data-transition="pop">
```

My Default.aspx.cs is as follows:

```
 if (Request.Form["custFullName"] != null || Request.Form["custFullName"] != "")
            {
                TowingDBDataContext db = new TowingDBDataContext();

                    tbl_quoteRequest newQuoteRequest = new tbl_quoteRequest();
                    newQuoteRequest.custName = Request.Form["custFullName"];
                    newQuoteRequest.custPhone = Request.Form["custPhoneNum"];
                    newQuoteRequest.custIssue = Request.Form["roadService"];
                    newQuoteRequest.custYear = Request.Form["carYearDB"];
                    newQuoteRequest.custMake = Request.Form["carMakeDB"];
                    newQuoteRequest.custModel = Request.Form["carModelDB"];

                    db.tbl_quoteRequests.InsertOnSubmit(newQuoteRequest);
            }
```

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: `db.tbl_quoteRequests.SubmitChanges();` ?

Comment: Just for the sake of future viewers it worked with:                      `db.SubmitChanges();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Heather's comment, the name of your form elements is not `custFullName` but `ctl00$MainContent$custFullName` (etc, same for all the other values)

```
newQuoteRequest.custName = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$custFullName"];
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you, for future understanding why does it sometimes allow you to use just the ID from the tag but other times it make you use `ctl00$MainContent$`?

Comment: It is because you use webforms, which decides on it's own which ids and names to use (based on the element's parents to guarantee uniqueness) and isn't really meant to be consumed by Request.Form code (normally you would use a model, an instance of a special class designed to hold all the form data). Also, if this answer helped you, please check it as the correct answer to the left of my message.